# Button not executing both functions when passing state and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm new to react and have encountered an issue which I haven't found any solution to for a while now.

The NEXT button is a child component of Form1 and is declared in App.js. The parameters of Form1 file is (props, {transform, fram}). The intention with props is to declare {props.children} in Form1 so that it allows the Next button to be shown by being implemented in App.js.

When implemented in this manner, the next button only seem to execute 1 function rather than 2 - handleNext() but not fram(). Fram() sets translateX value to form1. handleNext controls the state of CustomizedSteppers.

However, if the "props" is deleted from Form1, and the button is moved out of the   tags and put for example above CustomizedSteppers tag, it executes both functions. I want the button to be implemented in the manner that is shown below but it does not work as intended
My App.js:

```
import {Form1, Form2, Form3, Form4} from './components';
import {Header} from './containers';
import {Section} from './containers';
import {Forms} from './containers'
import CustomizedSteppers from './components/stepper/demo';
const App = () => {
  
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
      const handleNext = () => {
          setActiveStep((activeStep+1));
        };

  const [transform, transformit] = React.useState("TranslateX(0px)");
  
  const fram = () => {  
    transformit("TranslateX(-900px)");
  };
  return (
    <>  
      <Header />
        <Section class="section">
        
          <CustomizedSteppers activeStep={activeStep} handleNext={handleNext}/>
          <Forms>
            
            <Form1 transform={transform} fram={fram}>
              <button id="B "onClick={() => {handleNext();fram();}}>NEXT</button>  
            </Form1>
            <Form2 />
            <Form3 />
            <Form4 />
          </Forms>
        </Section>
        
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

My Form1.js:

```
export default function Form1(props, {transform, fram}){

  return (
    <div id='Form1' style={{transform: transform}}>
              <p id="demo"></p>
              <div class="btn-box-f1">
                {props.children}
              </div>
          </div>   
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to call two functions, call the function that updates the state first, and then use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to monitor that state change.

The `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  transformit('TranslateX(-900px)');
}, [activeStep]);
```

And the updated button:

```
<button id="B" onClick={handleNext}>NEXT</button>
```

Oh, and there's no need to have double parentheses in your `setActiveStep` function:

```
setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
```

Comment: I don't understand, the button only executes handleNext but not transform if I implement it like that or did I miss something :o? And what should be the parameters of Form1 in that case? Thanks otherwise!

Comment: How do i call the function that updates the state?

Comment: `handleNext` updates the state. `useEffect` watches for the change in state.

Comment: I've done those changes in my code u wrote but the form does not go -900px, only handleNext is being executed. Handlenext is taking care of the stepper and useEffect should take care of the forms position - but the latter doesn't do that

Comment: You need to start debugging your code to find out what errors are being exposed. `function Form1({ transform, fram, children }) {...}`, perhaps. No, that doesn't make sense. You're both trying calling the `fram` function, and trying to pass it down as a prop to your Form component. But `fram` isn't being used in that component.

Comment: Yea the error lies there. is there any other alternative to props and {props.children}? the button works as intended but not when including props in parameters and putting the button in desired place i.e. as a child component to form1.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the issue is with the way you've declared the `Form1` component's props. React components take only a single argument, the `props` object. `function Form1(props, { transform, fram })` is invalid, the `transform` prop isn't accessible in the component, it's undefined.

Here's the working version:

```
function Form1({ children, transform }) {
  return (
    <div id="Form1" style={{ transform: transform }}>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <div className="btn-box-f1">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit button-not-executing-both-functions-when-passing-state-and-props]

I've dropped logs in both callbacks and correctly see both triggered ***and*** see the `transform` applied to the `id="Form1"` `div` element.

[image]

Here the "next" button was clicked, both callbacks logged, the active step state updated to `1`, and the transform was applied.